# 12 hour clock not displaying, but 24 hour clock displaying fine

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code so that when I click the buttons, it switches between the 12 hours clock and 24 hours clock.

The 24 hour clock displayed, but when I click the 12 hour clock button, nothing happens.

Google Inspect also says nothing. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
function twelvehour() {
  var dat = new Date();
  var h = dat.getHours()
  if (h >= 13) {
    var h = dat.getHours() - 12
  } else {
    var h = dat.getHours()
  }
  var m = dat.getMinutes()
  var s = dat.getSeconds()
  if (h >= 12) {
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + "pm"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s
  }
}

function tfourhour() {
  var dat1 = new Date();
  var h1 = dat1.getHours()
  var m1 = dat1.getMinutes()
  var s1 = dat1.getSeconds()
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = h1 + ":" + m1 + ":" + s1
}
setInterval(twelvehour, 1000);
setInterval(tfourhour, 1000);
document.getElementById("twelve").onclick = twelvehour()
document.getElementById("tfour").onclick = tfourhour()
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    button {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Assignment 9c Clock</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" style="width=500, height=500" id="twelve">12 Hour Clock</button>
  <button type="button" style="width=500, height=500" id="tfour">24 Hour Clock</button>
  <br>
  <p id="clock"></p>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="sample4.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You run two functions at the same time by calling `setIterval` twice.
2. `twelvehour` function doesn't work properly since you set `h` before it displayed.
3. Event handlers should be mapped with a function itself not a result of it.

And consider using a function that store the selected function.

```js
let f = twelvehour;
f();
function twelvehour() {
  var dat = new Date();
  dat.setHours(14); // for test
  var h = dat.getHours()
  var m = dat.getMinutes()
  var s = dat.getSeconds()
  if (h >= 12) {
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = (h - 12) + ":" + m + ":" + s + "pm"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s
  }
}

function tfourhour() {
  var dat1 = new Date();
  dat1.setHours(14); // for test
  var h1 = dat1.getHours()
  var m1 = dat1.getMinutes()
  var s1 = dat1.getSeconds()
  document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = h1 + ":" + m1 + ":" + s1
}
setInterval(() => f(), 1000);
document.getElementById("twelve").onclick = () => { f = twelvehour; f(); }
document.getElementById("tfour").onclick = () => { f = tfourhour; f(); }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    button {
      display: inline-block;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Assignment 9c Clock</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" style="width=500, height=500" id="twelve">12 Hour Clock</button>
  <button type="button" style="width=500, height=500" id="tfour">24 Hour Clock</button>
  <br>
  <p id="clock"></p>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: nice solution. very clever

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue here is assigning `onclick` in a wrong way. You should drop the parentheses:

```js
document.getElementById("twelve").onclick = twelvehour
```

Or, put it in the HTML:

```html
<button type="button"
        style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"
        id="twelve"
        onclick="twelvehour()">12 Hour Clock</button>
```

Comment: You'll probably also want to assign the `setInterval` lines to variables so that you can call `clearInterval` so that the timers don't keep running and/or interfere with each other.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't want to mention all issues at once, as OP maybe could fix it himself after having his functions properly fired.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it:

```js
function Clock(displayFunc, twelveHour = true, interval = 1000){
  let clock;
  this.twelveHour = twelveHour; this.interval = interval;
  this.start = ()=>{
    const fun = ()=>{
      let d = new Date, h = d.getHours(), m = d.getMinutes(), s = d.getSeconds(), z = d.getMilliseconds(), p = false;
      if(this.twelveHour){
        if(h > 12){
          h -= 12; p = 'pm';
        }
        else{
          p = 'am';
        }
      }
      else if(h < 10){
        h = '0'+h;
      }
      if(m < 10)m = '0'+m;
      if(s < 10)s = '0'+s;
      if(z < 10){
        z = '00'+z;
      }
      else if(z < 99){
        z = '0'+z;
      }
      displayFunc({hours:h.toString(), minutes:m.toString(), seconds:s.toString(), am_pm:p});
    }
    fun(); clock = setInterval(fun, this.interval);
    return this;
  }
  this.stop = ()=>{
    clearInterval(clock); clock = undefined;
    return this;
  }
}
let doc, bod, I; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; bod = doc.body; I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
const digital = I('digital'), clock = new Clock(o=>{
  digital.textContent = o.hours+':'+o.minutes+':'+o.seconds+' '+o.am_pm;
});
clock.start();
}); // end load
```

```html
<div id='digital'></div>
```